# Python is giving me a lot of traceback stuff what is going on

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is my code

```
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con

while (1):
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('stickman.png', region=(150,175,350,600), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
        print("I can see it")
        time.sleep(0.5)
else:
    print("I am unable to see it")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TheJa\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('stickman.png', region=(150,175,350,600), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8) != None:
  File "C:\Users\TheJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TheJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TheJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 359, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "C:\Users\TheJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 134, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.
```

Comment: Looks like you need to import the Pillow package?

Comment: You need to install `pillow`. See https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for the suggestion. I have installed pillow using the pip command.

Comment: Maybe it's because I have 3 different versions of python in my computer

Comment: That's not "a lot of traceback stuff", that's a single traceback. It may be bewildering at first but you will quickly learn to make sense of it and find the useful information in each scenario. The reason it's a bit overwhelming is that different details are important in different situations.

Comment: Hi @tripleee thanks for the advice and encouragement!